# Check all checkbox taking long time to check all checkboxes in gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am using below code to check all checkboxes in gridview.
Gird in having approx 2000 to 2500 records. But it is taking long time to check all checkboxes also sometimes the page stops responding when clicked on checkall checkbox.

Please suggest improvement for this. It will be helpful.

```
function checkAll(checkAllBox)
        {

        var chkBoxId;
        chkBoxId = "chkSelect";     

        //alert(checkAllBox.value);


        //alert(chkBoxId);
        var chkState = checkAllBox.checked;

        for(i=0;i<document.Form1.length;i++)
        {
            e = document.Form1.elements[i];

            if(e.type == 'checkbox' && e.name.indexOf(chkBoxId) != -1)
            {
                checkAllBox.checked = chkState;
                if(e.disabled == false)
                {
                    e.checked=chkState;                     
                }       
            }
            else if(e.type == 'checkbox' && e.name.indexOf(chkBoxId) == -1)
            {
                if(chkState == true)
                {
                    e.checked = false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use javascript or jQuery

Answer (score 0):

solution is simple follow below steps.(1) First give one checkbox into header of grid view . (2) make change event of heading checkbox.(3) dyamically add checkbox into all row with addinng user defined class like :  (4) after that write function code into change event of header checkbox. wirte code. $('input:checkbox .yourclass').attr('checked',true).this code check all checkbox of table

Answer (score 0):

Having 2500 records on single page seems too much. you can think of using paging to show 50 or hundred records on a page. It will give you faster download and rendering of page.

You can use querySelector to get the better performance with simple and short code. Assuming the name of checkboxes starts with chkSelect so use `^` (starts with) wild card. Although you can use contains `*` or ends with `$` as well

```
var els = document.querySelector("[name^='chkSelect']");
for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
     els[i].checked = checkstate;
}
```

If you can use jQuery, you can use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$("[name^='chkSelect']").prop("checked", checkstate);
```

You can use the [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) if you have or can assign class to checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this lines of code

```
foreach(Control c in groupBox1.Controls)
{
 if(c is CheckBox)
 {
   CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)c;
    if(cb.Checked == false)
    {
       cb.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
       cb.Checked = false;
    }
 }
}
```

Instead of group box you can use grid,panel as well.